# Retrieving values from select list

Tags: c#, .net, watin

I recently started to use WatiN to test some stuff on a website.

And I would like to ask, is it possible: if I have a select list on my page, can I retrieve all the values with text from it in a dictionary?

Like let's say I have a list:

```
<SELECT NAME="mylist" onChange="disp_text()">
<OPTION VALUE="m1">Cape Fear
<OPTION VALUE="m2">The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
<OPTION VALUE="m3">The Omen
<OPTION VALUE="m4">The Godfather
<OPTION VALUE="m5">Forrest Gump
</SELECT>
```

So I would like to have a dictionary with those values `<string, string> dictionary.add(m1, "cape fear");`... etc

Is it possible to do with watin? And how?

---

Another question is when I click on a link it opens a new tab in IE, how do I close only that newly opened tab and continue doing work on the main page?

Comment: If you have two different questions, you should ask them separately on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with your first question

```
        SelectList region1 = browser.SelectList(Find.ByName("mylist"));
        Dictionary<string, string> optionsdictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (Option option in region1.Options)
        {
            optionsdictionary.Add(option.Value, option.Text);
        }
```

And for the second one, I tried this with FireFox and it works, but like Otiel said, you should post separate questions.

```
        browser.GoTo("http://news.google.co.in/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn");
        Link newslink = browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("somelink"));
        newslink.Click();
        FireFox newbrowser = FireFox.AttachTo<FireFox>(Find.ByUrl("somelink"));
        newbrowser.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could let linq do the hard work for you: -

```
SelectList regionLst = browser.SelectList(Find.ByName("mylist"));
Dictionary<string, string> optionsDictionary = regionLst.Options.ToDictionary(option => option.Value, option => option.Text);
```

Just one word of warning.  Both this example and the one provided by Ashish rely on there being no duplicate "option values" in your select list.  HTH!